# Global args in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'd like to pass the same `args` value to all containers and like to use it in substitution in the Dockerfile as well as the docker-compose.yml file. What would be the best way to do this?

example:

docker-compose:

```
args:
  foo: "BAR"
services:
  s1:
    build: .
  s2:
    image: foo/bar:${foo}
  ...
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG FOO
FROM bar/foo:$foo
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider the following:

```
FOO=BAR docker-compose up
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  s1:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        foo: ${FOO}
  s2:
    image: foo/bar:${FOO}
  ...
```

Dockerfile:

```
ARG foo
FROM bar/foo:$foo
...
ARG foo
RUN ... ${foo}...
```

You need one `ARG` before `FROM` if you want to use the var in the `FROM` line and one `ARG` after if you want to use the var after the `FROM` line.